# How does one apply hierarchical agglomerative clustering when multiple positions are equidistant (non-unique distance matrix)?

Tags: matrix, distance, hierarchical-clustering, ties

I have been following [this single/minimum -linkage example](https://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/hierarchical.html) to better understand hierarchical agglomerative clustering. I noticed that the entries of `d_ij` are unique for `i > j` (where `i` denotes the row and `j` denotes the column). This approach seems straight-forward. Although scipy exists, I am trying to code my own python routine and do not understand how to proceed in the case where `d_ij` are NOT unique for `i > j`; i.e., there are duplicate entries in the distance matrix. As an example, consider the following distance matrix:

```
 .. (6, 6) DISTANCE MATRIX:
[[ 0.          1.41421356  2.82842712  4.24264069  8.48528137 14.14213562]
 [ 1.41421356  0.          1.41421356  2.82842712  7.07106781 12.72792206]
 [ 2.82842712  1.41421356  0.          1.41421356  5.65685425 11.3137085 ]
 [ 4.24264069  2.82842712  1.41421356  0.          4.24264069  9.89949494]
 [ 8.48528137  7.07106781  5.65685425  4.24264069  0.          5.65685425]
 [14.14213562 12.72792206 11.3137085   9.89949494  5.65685425  0.        ]]
```

Let the row index `i` and column index `j` equal to `0` represent position `A`, `1` represent `B`, ..., and `5` represent `F`. We find the non-zero minimum is `1.41421356`; these are distances `d_AB`, `d_BC`, `d_CD`. Equivalently, we can list:

`d_0,1` or `d_1,0`

`d_1,2` or `d_2,1`

`d_2,3` or `d_3,2`

In the case WITHOUT duplicate distances, the two positions corresponding to the minimum distance are effectively removed from the distance matrix. But in this case, since multiple positions are equidistant, one cannot simply remove these positions as they are still needed to calculate the distance between non-equidistant positions; i.e., there are still distances `d_AC` and `d_AD` and `d_BD` (or equivalently, `d_0,2`/`d_2,0`, `d_0,3`/`d_3,0`, `d_1,3`/`d_3,1`).

How does one apply agglomerative clustering when multiple positions are equidistant?

Comment: These are called ties in a distance matrix. It often happens with distances computed on binned or on categorical attributes. Unfortunately, there is no satisfactory solution of the issue. Try to sort randomly  the objects in the data (that is hence to permute rows/columns of the distance matrix) several times and do the clustering each time. Compare results. This is called stability check. If it turns to be not stable (object composition of the clusters "drifts" considerably) don't do clustering with your data. Consider changing data or another sort of analysis.

Comment: `How does one apply agglomerative clustering when multiple positions are equidistant?` There is no reasonable ground to modify algorithm because of ties because it is unclear how it could be bettered in the face of various distribution/pattern of ties locations in the matrix.